# Track user between two different server

Tags: node.js, session, spring-boot, cross-domain

I have 2 server :

1) Apache tomcat server on port 8443 using Spring boot

2) Node server on port 443

both of them are https.

Now the application is designed in such a way that server 1 handles the login page & server 2 handles the dashboard

So a user sign in using : https //localhost:8443/login

and after successful login I do a

window.open(https //localhost:443/dashboard?userName=xyz,"_self");

which redirects the user to dashboard hosted by node server.

Now my problem is if a user directly hits https //localhost:443/dashboard?userName=xyz, then he can acces the dashboard which is wrong.

User should always access the dashboard only after login.

But i can't use session as session cannot be shared between 2 servers.

So how do i keep a track if user has loged in server 1 & he is allowed to see the dashboard in server 2?

Also I'm planning to buy a domain
But how do I host it over 2 ports? ( 8443 & 443)

I want something like
1) https //example.com/login ( port 8443)
2) https //example.com/dashboard?userName=xyz  ( port 443 )

Comment: Please take a look at this article regarding session stickiness:
http://serverfault.com/questions/32421/how-is-session-stickiness-achieved-across-multiple-web-servers

Answer (score 2):

For the question about keeping track of the user you can do the following (custom solution, you can achieve this with existing products also). Points 2 a and b are concurrent.

1. After a successful login generate a token on the first server

2.a. Send the token as a parameter to the redirect

2.b. Send the token from the first server to the second (through HTTP maybe) and associate it to the user

3. Check the token associated to the user with what comes from the redirect. If these do not match throw an error

As for the domain, you can set up a reverse proxy, like Apache and redirect different paths to different servers. Example: /login would go to one port and the rest to the other

Comment: Thanks @Alexandru, I'll try the custom solution.
You also mentioned about existing products. Can you name some products? which I can go through?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a similar approach to the one Alexandru gave but with a twist - login should generate [JWT](https://jwt.io/)s and encode all the relevant authentication information there so that your node.js server can verify it and use to authorize the user accordingly.

As for the second part of your question, Apache or nginx should suffice, just like Alexandru suggested.